# Highlight a Imagebutton to show notifications

Tags: android, android-button

I have an application in which you can accept friend request. For this purpose i have kept an activity which will start when an image button is pressed.

When my application starts i want to check if the user has any requests and if yes the button should be highlighted.

How do i do this?

Comment: try to set `setFocusableInTouchMode(true),setFocusable(true),requestFocus(true)` for imagebutton or plz post some code

Comment: @imrankhan Sorry, but i guess u got me wrong. I dont want to highlight it when clicked but when i have some requests in background!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another  highlighted colour image. and Set TextView on that image.

Ex: RelativeLayout for that RelativeLayout background is your highlighted colour image then set TextView on that RelativeLayout.

Based on your condition put this image and number of pendings to TextView

Answer (score 0):

you could make two imagebuttons. One which is in your normal colour and one in the highlighted colour, which are on the same place.
Depending on the situation you make either the one or the other (in-)visible.

Comment: this can be an alternative but not the exact solution, I mean what is i want to show the number of friend requests highlighted, just like facebook?